# How do I get pipe to work when passed in string for sh -c and su is involved

Tags: sh, su

The pipe `|` to `grep` doesn't work -- it prints all the lines:

```
su - root -s /usr/bin/sh -c "java -version|grep build"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java -version` writes to standard error, not standard output.

```
su - root -s /usr/bin/sh -c "java -version 2>&1 |grep build"
```

`2>&1` copies standard error to standard output, so that it gets fed through the pipe and into `grep`.

That said, `grep` doesn't have to be run as root, assuming the pipeline isn't being specified for use by something that just runs arbitrary code using `su sh -c '...'`.

```
su - root -s /usr/bin/sh -c 'java -version' 2>&1 | grep build
```

Comment: Ofcourse! I forgot about this. I did tackle this a while back. Thanks for answering chepner